# How convert a future date to the yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z format with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, time

I am trying to get this to work in PowerShell with no success.
I would need to convert a future date and time (let's say July 1st 2022 midnight 00:00) to the format yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z

The below command:

```
Get-Date -Format u
```

outputs to 2022-06-21 13:34:20Z (at the time of writing), which is pretty close to what i need for the present time.

Is there a way to get what i need without the use of `regex` or `replace()` method and also in the future?

Comment: You mentioned that it is pretty close to what you need.  If you do `(get-date).GetDateTimeFormats()` and find the one you want in the array, you can then use the index of the desired format to get what you need.  Example formatting would be `$((Get-Date).GetDateTimeFormats()[94])`

Comment: Accounting for the future date piece in line with the accepted answer you would do `$futuredate = (Get-Date).AddDays(30)` and then `$((Get-Date $futuredate).GetDateTimeFormats()[94])` assuming you don't need the 'T' and 'Z'

Comment: I need the T and Z, that is how the time looks like in Azure Portal `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is pretty flexible. Just specify it manually:

```
Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ
```

Output: 2022-06-21T03:51:17Z

For a future date, it's probably easier to create that in advance, then use it with the formatting:

```
$futuredate = (Get-Date).AddDays(30)
Get-Date $futuredate -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
```

Output: 2022-07-21T03:56:46Z

Or, if in your case you really do want exactly midnight for the day in question:

```
$futuredate = (Get-Date).AddDays(10).Date
Get-Date $futuredate -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
```

Output: 2022-07-01T00:00:00Z

Comment: Thanks. I will use this logic to modulate the number of days i would like to add to the date I'm compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above answer, i tried to come up with a version of getting the first day of the next month and the last day. Let me know your thoughts:

Beggining of month:

```
Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00Z" -Date ([datetime](Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(1))
```

Output: 2022-07-01T00:00:00Z

End of month:

```
Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddT23:59:59Z"-Date (([datetime](Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(2)).AddDays(-1))
```

Output: 2022-07-31T23:59:59Z